# Insert multiple values in SQL, failed to convert

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have an SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE [jato].[option_list](
    [vehicle_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [option_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [option_type] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [option_code] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [manuf_name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [id_902] [float] NULL,
    [id_903] [float] NULL,
    [id_904] [float] NULL,
    [id_905] [float] NULL,
    [id_100902] [float] NULL,
    [id_100903] [float] NULL,
    [id_100904] [float] NULL,
    [id_100905] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OPTIONLIST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [vehicle_id] ASC,
    [option_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I want to insert values in it.

The following query works:

```
INSERT INTO jato.option_list 
(vehicle_id,option_id,option_type,option_code,manuf_name,id_902,id_903,id_904,id_905,id_100902,id_100903,id_100904,id_100905) 

values
(11280320191201,1142,'C','MG','Machine Grey Metallic',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

but if I add other values in same query, I encounter a fail conversion from `varchar` to int whereas my columns order has not changed. For example the following query doesn't works, I have an error when SQL converting 'MG' to int:

```
INSERT INTO jato.option_list 
(vehicle_id,option_id,option_type,option_code,manuf_name,id_902,id_903,id_904,id_905,id_100902,id_100903,id_100904,id_100905) 

values
(11280320191201,1142,'C','MG','Machine Grey Metallic',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(11688620170510,1190,'O',881,'Automatic boot pull down',635.25,525,0,0,635.25,525,0,0)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the second line of values:

```
(11688620170510,1190,'O',881,'Automatic boot pull down',635.25,525,0,0,635.25,525,0,0)
```

Change that to:

```
(11688620170510,1190,'O','881','Automatic boot pull down',635.25,525,0,0,635.25,525,0,0)
```

Then it will work. To summarize, you code should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.option_list 
(vehicle_id,option_id,option_type,option_code,manuf_name,id_902,id_903,id_904,id_905,id_100902,id_100903,id_100904,id_100905) 

values
(11280320191201,1142,'C','MG','Machine Grey Metallic',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(11688620170510,1190,'O','881','Automatic boot pull down',635.25,525,0,0,635.25,525,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So,
I found myself an answer. I had to type the values in same format for all rows.

In my case :

```
INSERT INTO jato.option_list 
(vehicle_id,option_id,option_type,option_code,manuf_name,id_902,id_903,id_904,id_905,id_100902,id_100903,id_100904,id_100905) 

values
(11280320191201,1142,'C','MG','Machine Grey Metallic',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(11688620170510,1190,'O',881,'Automatic boot pull down',635.25,525,0,0,635.25,525,0,0)
```

had to be :

```
INSERT INTO jato.option_list 
(vehicle_id,option_id,option_type,option_code,manuf_name,id_902,id_903,id_904,id_905,id_100902,id_100903,id_100904,id_100905) 

values
(11280320191201,1142,'C','MG','Machine Grey Metallic',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
(11688620170510,1190,'O','881','Automatic boot pull down',635.25,525,0,0,635.25,525,0,0)
```

I had to add some quotes near to 881.

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason for the error in the statement is the fact, that you use `VALUES` table value constructor. In this situation, as is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#data-types), the *values specified in a multi-row INSERT statement follow the data type conversion properties of the UNION ALL syntax. This results in the implicit conversion of unmatched types to the type of higher precedence*.

So, with the data in the question, the value `'MG'` (`varchar`) from the first row is implicitly converted to `int`, because you have `881` (`int`) in the second row and the `int` datatype has a higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) order than the `varchar` datatype.

Execute the `INSERT` statement in one of the following ways:

- Using a single statement and the approapriate `varchar` data type (values `'MG'` and `'881'` for column `option_code`)
- Using two separate statements and `varchar` and `int` data types (values `'MG'` and `881` for column `option_code`)

Single `INSERT` statement with appropriate data types:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.option_list 
(vehicle_id,option_id,option_type,option_code,manuf_name,id_902,id_903,id_904,id_905,id_100902,id_100903,id_100904,id_100905) 
VALUES
   (11280320191201,1142,'C','MG','Machine Grey Metallic',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
   (11688620170510,1190,'O','881','Automatic boot pull down',635.25,525,0,0,635.25,525,0,0)
```

Two `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.option_list (vehicle_id,option_id,option_type,option_code,manuf_name,id_902,id_903,id_904,id_905,id_100902,id_100903,id_100904,id_100905) 
VALUES
   (11280320191201,1142,'C','MG','Machine Grey Metallic',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

INSERT INTO dbo.option_list (vehicle_id,option_id,option_type,option_code,manuf_name,id_902,id_903,id_904,id_905,id_100902,id_100903,id_100904,id_100905)
VALUES
   (11688620170510,1190,'O',881,'Automatic boot pull down',635.25,525,0,0,635.25,525,0,0)
```